# cython - using c99 function under windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, cython, c99

I am using Cython to speed up some of my Python code. I used it successfully before. But now I need to import some functions from libc.math in my .pyx file.

```
from libc.math cimport lgamma, exp, log
```

and get the following error when I try to build the file.

```
> python setup.py build_ext -i
```

> running build_ext
>
> cythoning tradeclass.pyx to tradeclass.c
>
> building 'tradeclass' extension
>
> C:\Users\js\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for
>   Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBU G
>
> ...
>
> tradeclass.c(4969) : warning C4013: 'lgamma' undefined; assuming extern returning int
>
> ...
>
> C:\Users\js\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LIB
>   PATH:C:\Users\js\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\js\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\PCbuild\amd64 /
>   LIBPATH:C:\Users\js\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\PC\VS9.0\amd64 /EXPORT:inittradeclass build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\tradecla
>   ss.obj "/OUT:h:\Classification\Classification Algos\My Algo beta dist\tradeclass.pyd" /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\tradecl
>   ass.lib /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\tradeclass.pyd.manifest
>
> ...
>
> Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\tradeclass.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\tradeclass.exp
>   tradeclass.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol lgamma referenced in function __pyx_f_10tradeclass_betapdf

Without the lgamma function in my pyx-script the file gets build without any error. After extensive search I found that C99 functions (which lgamma belongs to) from libc.math have problems to work under Windows (I use Windows 7).

Why is that and more importantly **what can I do so that I can use lgamma in my pyx-script**?

(I use python as a scientist and not as a developer, so my knowledge of the inner workings of a computer and operating systems is very limited as is my vocabulary of the terms used in these areas.)

Comment: `lgamma` and other C99 functions were added around 2013 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/07/19/c99-library-support-in-visual-studio-2013/. Visual C++ 9 comes from 2008(ish). Therefore it isn't supported. You might be able to use a later version of Visual C++ or use the mingw gcc compiler instead but both of those come with their own complications and I can't tell you how to install them.

Comment: What's wrong with `scipy.special.gammaln`?

Comment: thanks for the info about the release time of C99 functions in visual studio. It is recommended that one uses the same VS version that python was build with. So it seems I have to update to Python 3.5 to be able to use a VS version later than 2013. Btw, I cannot use gammaln from scipy because I need to use the function within a loop in my cython code and that would then slow it down immensely.

Comment: I'd be tempted to look for other implementations of `lgamma` first. One option would be to copy the Cython code that scipy uses to implement theirs (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/_loggamma.pxd). You'd also need to copy some of the dependencies too.